# Should I normalize or standardize my dataset for knn?

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, knn

I trying to use knn for a classification task and my dataset contains **categorical features which are one hot encoded**, **numerical features like price etc..** and also **BoW(CountVectorizer)** vectors for my text column.

I know knn is affected by scaling. So I am confused what to use here?

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.preprocessing import Normalizer
from sklearn.preprocessing import normalize
```

Comment: `StandardScaler` for numerical features should be enough.

Comment: @SergeyBushmanov Many rows in the price column are zeros? Can I still standardize using standardscaler?

Comment: Your observation that many prices are zeroes may lead you to an other feature preprocessing pipeline, but in general, one would apply `StandardScaler` on numerical features with differing scale. This is important for KNN

Comment: @SergeyBushmanov I've a small query. You mentioned to standardize only my numerical features but I've applied PCA on my BoW features and I was thinking whether I should standardize them as well along with numerical features and leave out categorical features.

Comment: BoW are already well behaving features. I would guess you do not need to standardize them. However, if you wish to you can always cross validate if that makes sense.

Comment: Thanks you again :) I hope you can answer this one last query. I have used PCA on my BoW because to reduce dimensions as for large dimensions knn is taking a lot of time. Originally I had around 55K dimensions for BoW. I ploted the pca variance ratio and seen that around 72% variance is explained in first 500 dimension and 80% variance is explained in 1000 dimension and 85% is explained in around 2K dimensions? Which would be your choice? I'm confused on what to pick as it's taking a lot of time to execute.

Comment: Nobody but Cross Validation can tell you the answer. Just in case you are under time pressure with your KNN. There exists faster KNN algos with GPU like `kmcuda`

Comment: @SergeyBushmanov I asked the question because I am not been able to cross validate due to not having enough time. Is kmcuda similar to scikit learn KNeighborsClassifier algorithm? does it provide a similar output? It seems like kmeans clustering algorithm

Comment: `kmcuda`, as `KNeighborsClassifier`, will produce cluster memberships, but at least 10x faster.

Comment: @SergeyBushmanov Does it provide probabilities similar to `knn.predict_proba()`for classification task?

Comment: No, as far as know, only classes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion would be to go for [MinMaxScaler](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html#scaling-features-to-a-range)

One of the major reason is that your features such as price can't have negative values and as you mentioned, it could be sparse.

**From Documentation:**

> The motivation to use this scaling include robustness to very small
>   standard deviations of features and preserving zero entries in sparse
>   data.

At the same time, if your numerical variable has a huge variance, then go for [RobustScaler](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html#scaling-data-with-outliers) or [StandardScaler](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html#standardization-or-mean-removal-and-variance-scaling).

You dont have to scale the one hot encoded features.

For BoW, it is important to preserve the sparsity of the data. If you apply the StandardScaler, you will lose the sparsity. You definitely have to go for MinMaxScaler.
Another option would be to go for [TfidfVectorizer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer), which does the l2 normalization by default.

Comment: Can I know what you meant by preserving the sparsity of the data. Actually I've used PCA on my BoW and transformed into fewer dimension. So can I now apply scaling to it or let it be.

Comment: `preserving the sparsity of the data` means zeros in the features would be kept as zeros even after Normalization. Sparsity simply means having less number of nonzero values. BoW usually have a lot zeros because every document does not contain all the words in the vocabulary.